# Flutter update a value with provider on the previous page

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have a **ChangeNotifier** called `MyProvider`.
In my `View1`  page, I call `MyProvider` to display a `myNumber` variable which is a number and which I initialize to 5.

On my `View1` page, I have a button that pushes me to a `View2` page that also calls `MyProvider`.

On my `View2` page, I have a button that increments my `myNumber` variable.

When I return to my `View1` page with a Navigator.pop the `myNumber` variable is not updated. How to do ?

**Here the router:**

```
case RouterName.kView1:
  return CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => MyProvider(),
        child: Consumer<MyProvider>(builder :(ctx , provider , child){
          return View1();
        }),
      )
  );

case RouterName.kView2:
  return CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => MyProvider(),
        child: Consumer<MyProvider>(builder :(ctx , provider , child){
          return View2();
        }),
      )
  );
```

**My myProvider:**

```
class MyProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  // Variables
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  late int myNumber;
  Future? templateDataToLoad;
  late LoadingState templateDataState;

  // Constructor
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  MyProvider(){
    _initialise();
  }

  // Initialisation
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future _initialise() async
  {
    templateDataState = LoadingState.isReady;
    templateDataToLoad = await loadingData();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future loadingData() async
  {
    myNumber= 5;
    templateDataState = LoadingState.isSuccess;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // Functions public
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void edit()
  {
    myNumber = 6;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
}
```

**In the `View1` for show `myNumber`:**

```
Consumer<MyProvider>(
    builder: (context, mymodel, child){
      return Text(mymodel.myNumber.toString());
    }
),
```

**In the `View1` the button for go to the View2:**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    RouterName.kView2,
)
```

In the `View2` I call the edit method in my `myProvider`. And After I return on the `View1` but `myNumber` value is always 5 instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code, your `View1` and `View2`'s `MyProvider` is different:

```
case RouterName.kView1:
  return CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
        // create a new MyProvider in View1 page
        create: (BuildContext context) => MyProvider(),
        child: Consumer<MyProvider>(builder :(ctx , provider , child){
          return View1();
        }),
      )
  );

case RouterName.kView2:
  return CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
        // create another MyProvider in View2 page
        create: (BuildContext context) => MyProvider(),
        child: Consumer<MyProvider>(builder :(ctx , provider , child){
          return View2();
        }),
      )
  );
```

You can define your common `MyProvider` like this:

```
MyProvider myProvider = MyProvider();

case RouterName.kView1:
  return CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>.value(
        value: myProvider,
        child: Consumer<MyProvider>(builder :(ctx , provider , child){
          return View1();
        }),
      )
  );

case RouterName.kView2:
  return CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>.value(
        value: myProvider,
        child: Consumer<MyProvider>(builder :(ctx , provider , child){
          return View2();
        }),
      )
  );
```